# How do I map a host inside of an android application?

Tags: android, dns, apache-httpclient-4.x

We have several servers behind a load balancer, this balancer will point to different servers depending on what the requested domain was. Some of the domains are not public and therefore must be provided by an in-house dns solution or hosts file.

I have an android application which when in debug mode needs to be able to connect to our testing servers. The issue is that we want this to work in the field without having to alter the hosts file of everyone who will be testing this. I'm sure there has to be a way to map an IP address to a domain name inside of my application's network class before I make requests.

Can someone point me to documentation about mapping IPs to domains using the DefaultHttpClient or anything similar? Thanks.